# What is really being asked in this question?

Tags: r

I have this assignment which I am not quiet sure if I understood correctly so I am going to ask from any of you who understands it some help:

**Could there be a difference between genders in terms of how long they use Instagram. Visualize these two distributions and describe the outcome. Your 
choice for visualization geom in question 5 means you need to think 
critically about how to visualize these two distributions.**

So, from what I understood from above I have done this:

```
SurveyInstaMen <- SurveyInsta %>% filter(Gender == "Man") %>% 

ggplot(SurveyInsta, mapping=aes(x=Usage_duration , fill=Gender)) +
geom_bar(position="stack", color="grey")+
coord_flip()
```

and here is the data set(Usage_duration and Gender columns):

```
| Usage_duration |  Gender  |
-----------------------------
|  76.5          |  Man     |
|  5.5           |  Female  |
|  10.0          |  Female  |
|  12.0          |  Man     |
```

Am I following the wrong approach? Did I misunderstood the question?

dput:

```
structure(list(Usage_duration = c(76.5, 5.5, 10, 12), Gender = c("Man", 
"Female", "Female", "Man")), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

EDIT:
this is the screenshot after I implemented the second suggestion from Dij
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GL3cf.png)

Comment: maybe you're better off with `geom_boxplot` instead

Comment: @Dij ok can you post an answer with an further explanation of how you would implement that because I am new to R?

Comment: you mapped the distribution to the `x` aesthetic in `geom_boxplot`, I have updated the code in the answer below.

Comment: based on your screenshot, it looks like your Usage_duration column is not numeric (and is probably a factor) hence the values are distributed across the y axis. Try running `class(SurveyInsta$Usage_duration)`. If you don't get a result indicating that the variable is `numeric` then convert it and re-run the code.

Comment: based on your screenshot, it looks like your Usage_duration column is not numeric (and is probably a factor) hence the values are distributed across the y axis. Try running `class(SurveyInsta$Usage_duration)`. If you don't get a result indicating that the variable is `numeric` then convert it and re-run the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To visualize the *distribution* of a variable you can use `geom_boxplot` (or `geom_histogram`, or `geom_density`, or `geom_violin`, etc.).

For `geom_boxplot`, you are visualizing the distribution along the y axis, so `Usage_duration` is best mapped to the `y` aesthetic.

```
SurveyInsta <- structure(list(Usage_duration = c(76.5, 5.5, 10, 12), 
               Gender = c("Man", "Female", "Female", "Man")), 
          row.names = c(NA, -4L), 
          class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

ggplot(SurveyInsta, aes(y = Usage_duration, fill = Gender)) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

[image: bxplt]

Comment: look at the screenshot I uploaded in my question using ur code.

Comment: I'm sorry, are you suggesting you only have those four rows of data? There is no distribution to visualize in that case.

Comment: no there are more than four rows but I only posted those four for brevity

Comment: your example is not reproducible

Comment: I am giving you the needed data for reproducing, what are you talking about?

Comment: I suggest checking out this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I just tried your suggestion and still the same problem, please check the update for the new image

Comment: providing a summary table of your data is NOT equivalent to supplying a minimally reproducible excerpt of your data.

Comment: whats the difference? How can I post the entire table here? that's not possible, the important thing is to have minimal reproducible data and I provided you that.

Comment: yours is not reproducible because based on the code provided, you should not get the output that you have screenshotted. This is avoided when you accurately reproduce your own data, your session info, whatever information is required to reproduce the error you are receiving. People on SO are trying to help you, but need enough information to do so.